# jQuery mobile.navigate changes url, doesn't load new page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, swipe

I've found a few similar posts through searches but none of their fixes seem to work for me.

I'm trying to change pages on swipe with jquery. The page url is getting updated on swipe, however it isn't bringing me to the new page. Instead it remains on the same page and only the url gets updated.

If anyone can take a quick look and suggest some possible fixes it'd be a huge help.

here's my code:

```
$(function(){
  $( "div.sw_box" ).on( "swipe", swipeHandler );

  function swipeHandler( event ){
    $.mobile.navigate("/test2.php");
  }
});
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There's an official example of swipe-to-navigate here: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0/docs/examples/swipe/swipe-page.html

You should try `$.mobile.changePage` instead of `$.mobile.navigate`; that seems like the most significant difference between the docs and your code

Comment: thank you but I've already taken a look at the docs and changePage and navigate are giving me the same results atm.

Answer (score 0):

$mobile.changepage is deprecated and will be removed by JQuery mobile 1.5.

This should work fine:

```
function swipeHandler( event ){
    $(':mobile-pagecontainer').pagecontainer('change', 'page.html', {
        transition: 'flip',
        changeHash: false,
        showLoadMsg: true
    });
}
```

in your case you'll need to change 'page.html' to 'test2.php' or you can use '#pageID' if pages are in the same document.